# What will be the correct word for "in a fine condition"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm unable to remember a word which relates to a fine and nice state. The word is like `?-shape`. Also, where and how can I use this word. Can I use it for both living and inanimate things.

Comment: Are you thinking of "ship-shape"?  It is usually used to describe inanimate things/places, but you might come from an encouraging doctor's visit and tell someone, "The doctor says everything is "ship-shape".

Comment: Yes, the word is right, can you elaborate more as an answer.

Comment: @SharadGautam: you could try looking online yourself, you know. Googling just "shipshape" would work.

Comment: I couldn't remember the word.

Comment: Can you just tick the correct answer so the question can be wrapped-up?

Comment: My sense is that _ship-shape_ means something closer to "in good order" than to "in [a] fine condition." For the latter I would expect a term such as "flawless" or "mint condition" to be a more suitable synonym.

Comment: Can mint condition be used for living things? @SvenYargs

Comment: No, I don't think so—except, I suppose, for a prosperous patch of wintergreen or spearmint. But on the other hand, I don't think _ship-shape_ works very well for living things either. For a living creature in fine condition, you might want to use an adjective like "thriving" or "in peak condition."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"**Ship-shape**" - ([hyphen may be optional] Borrowed from nautical terminology) Because of the nature of travel on a moving surface (water) it is essential that equipment/cargo/personnel are well-maintained and in the right place at the right time. "*Ship-shape*" refers to the optimum state of affairs in this regard.

We also borrow the expressions:

"*Squared-away*" -'Putting things in their proper place' - literally or figuratively.(Setting the masts and yardarms at right-angles (squared) to the keel of the ship.)

"*Batten down the hatches*" - 'Prepare for a storm' - literally or figuratively. (Securing and covering points of egress in the hold to prevent water from entering.)

"Stowed-away/Stowaway/'Stow it'" - Gear, or equipment, put away in it's place/A living thing (accidentally or purposely) traveling in a place reserved for equipment or gear - or an unauthorized person on board/'Take that comment/opinion and keep it to yourself' - 'Shut-up.'